# What is the public URL of my EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip-address

[Some sources](http://blog.impiyush.me/2015/02/running-ipython-notebook-server-on-aws.html) suggest that it's `https://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/` (where `xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx` is the public IP address of the machine). But when I navigate there Chrome says `This site can’t be reached`.

Comment: If in doubt, just use the Public IP address instead of a URL. The URL just points to the IP address, so it's the same thing. (Well, not totally -- if the DNS name is resolved inside the VPC where the EC2 instance resides, then it will actually resolve to the private IP address.)

Answer (score 13):

Just use `host` command and specify your public IP - it will show you the right URL, e.g.

```
$ host 52.204.122.132
132.122.204.52.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer ec2-52-204-122-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
```

where `ec2-52-204-122-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com` is your domain.

So you can add `https://` in front of it to access the instance via HTTPS.

Comment: What is url in above example?

Comment: The address is `ec2-52-204-122-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com`, so you can add `https://` in front of it, if you'd like to access your instance via HTTPS.

Answer (score 5):

When you access an URL from any browser, you need to make sure there is a server running on port 80, that is the default port. If you just launched a Linux ec2 instance, it's only accessible through ssh. To access these instances you need de access certificate, generated during the launch process and a ssh client, like ssh for Linux or putty for Windows. Also, if you do have a service running on port 80 or any other, you should make sure these ports are opened in the security policy of your instance.

Answer (score 1):

The Public DNS and IP address both can be used directly in the browser. You just have to open the ports 80 (http) and 443 (https, not necessary, still...).

You have to upload the file to /var/www/html to host your website.